# What is the drink, and who makes it?

Tags: riddle

> Need a drink?
>   Yes.
>   Cold?
>   No.
>   Fill me up!
>   Ok.
>   I'll tell you when it's ready!
>   Thanks.

**What is the drink, and who makes it?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that it is:

> Tea from a tea kettle. The kettle whistles when the water is ready and boiling.

Comment: It also explains "cold?" because (rot13) grn pna or gnxra ubg be pbyq (vprq grn).

Answer (score 2):

The drink could be

> Water, from a water cooler that has both a cold tap and a hot tap.

In this case, the maker is...

> A robotic voice-operated water cooler. It asks the user whether they want cold or hot water, rather than letting the user press the taps manually. Also, the machine makes a noise when it is finished dispensing water.

Answer (score 1):

It is...

> Coffee from a coffeemaker.

Because...

> You fill it up with water and grounds, it boils the water, and you can tell it's done when it beeps at you (or, for the low-tech, when you hear it stop that guttural brewing noise)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil Oh, I VTCed after answering. I considered adding several posts with different answers, or just jamming a bunch in here, but decided against it.

Comment: I agree it is too broad - have also VTC